# Right side of bootstrap container-fluid div is going outside of page wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out why the margin-left class on app-wrapper is messing up container-fluid. The right side of the container-fluid is getting pushed out of the page. The margin-left class is there to push app-wrapper away from the sidebar which is 50px wide.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100vh;
}

#app-sidebar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #102027;
    float: left;
}

#app-wrapper {
    margin-left: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}

#header-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#subheader {
    background-color: #37474f;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#subheader h4 {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 15.4px;
    margin-bottom: 15.4px;
}

#content {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    height: calc(100% - 130px);
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 11.5px;
    margin-bottom: 11.5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="app-sidebar"></div>
    <div id="app-wrapper">
        <div id="header-wrapper">
            <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
                Logo Goes Here
            </div>
            <div id="subheader" class="container-fluid">
                    <h4>Page Title Goes Here</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="container-fluid"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

See the below image (notice the right side, no padding is showing):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding padding with #content's padding:

```
padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
padding-top: 15px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 0px;
```

**EDIT:**

Initially I was looking at the content, but misunderstood the question.  The op clarified with a screenshot that it was the header where the concern was.  Adding a width to the wrapper to account for the offset introduced by the margin added for the sidebar provided the solution:

```
#header-wrapper {
    width: calc( 100% - 50px);
}
```

Try this:

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100vh;
}

#app-sidebar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #102027;
    float: left;
}

#app-wrapper {
    margin-left: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}

#header-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    height: 100px;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#subheader {
    background-color: #37474f;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#subheader h4 {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 15.4px;
    margin-bottom: 15.4px;
}

#content {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    height: calc(100% - 130px);
}

#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 11.5px;
    margin-bottom: 11.5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="app-sidebar"></div>
    <div id="app-wrapper">
        <div id="header-wrapper">
            <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
                Logo Goes Here
            </div>
            <div id="subheader" class="container-fluid">
                    <h4>Page Title Goes Here</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="container-fluid"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I inspected element on your snippet result and it didn't seem to fix it. I believe it is actually the Margin-Left on app-wrapper that is causing it. I am doing the Margin-Left to push it away from the sidebar...

Comment: Ah I see now what you are referring to if I try that with the page title.

Comment: yeah, I don't get it. We can remove the padding from content all together and it still happens. I believe it has something to do with the margin-left: 50px on app-wrapper, but I believe I need that to push my main content away from the sidebar.

Comment: padding: 0 50px; to app-wrapper

Comment: still no luck, see the pic I added to bottom of post.

Comment: I didn't notice the heading was fixed :P  You can set the width to use calc(100% - 50px); - I updated the snippet thing in my answer for testing

Comment: Wow! That did it. However, I don't think it has anything to do with the heading being fixed. I just think it was the Width: 100% on app-wrapper that was messing me up. 100% doesn't work when sidebar is already taking up 50px. Does this make sense? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`padding-right` is actually 0 in your code. padding values go top,right,bottom,left. So, `padding: 15px 0 15px 0;` makes padding-right = 0 and padding-left = 15px
change padding to `padding: 15px 15px 0 0;`.

you need to fix width of footer and header-wrapper using `calc(100% - 50px)`

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100vh;
}

#app-sidebar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #102027;
    float: left;
}

#app-wrapper {
    margin-left: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}

#header-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    calc(100% - 50px);
    height: 100px;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#subheader {
    background-color: #37474f;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#subheader h4 {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 15.4px;
    margin-bottom: 15.4px;
}

#content {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    height: calc(100% - 130px);
    margin-left: 40px;
}

#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    height: 30px;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 11.5px;
    margin-bottom: 11.5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="app-sidebar"></div>
    <div id="app-wrapper">
        <div id="header-wrapper">
            <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
                Logo Goes Here
            </div>
            <div id="subheader" class="container-fluid">
                    <h4>Page Title Goes Here</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                    tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                    leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                    dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                    Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis
                    maximus eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque
                    sem. Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat
                    ac risus quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend
                    enim. Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet
                    nisl egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit
                    orci id mauris condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus
                    molestie pellentesque lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non
                    tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio.
                    Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis, in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed
                    porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate
                    interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis
                    varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis,
                    eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus.
                    Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero.
                    Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit.
                    Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
                    ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim. Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque
                    leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac
                    augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu
                    sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus
                    in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique
                    elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget
                    vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra orci non nulla tempus congue.
                    Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie. Nunc mattis blandit ligula
                    eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat tortor.
                </p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="container-fluid"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I really thought this was going to be the problem, but when I inspect the container-fluid divs of your code snippet in Chrome I am still only seeing the left padding. We can remove the padding from content all together and the issue will still exist.

Comment: you don't want left padding?

Comment: removed left padding. see now

Comment: No, I want the left and right padding that comes with the container-fluid class. The issue is that it is overflowing outside of the screen or something. Right click and inspect any div that has container-fluid on it and you will see what I mean.

Comment: see the pic I added to the bottom of my post.

Comment: @BlakeRivell its fixed now. check! if we fix width of footer and header-wrapper it solves the problem. to fix width just `calc(100% - 50px)`

Comment: It is actually the width of app-wrapper that needs to be fixed at the outer level. I really appreciate your help tonight. I am sure your solution is fine too, but it is cleaner to set it on app-wrapper.